# ubuntu 16.04 pyinstaller

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, pyinstaller

ubuntu 16.04 
pyinstaller 3.5 dev
python 3.5

I am trying to create an executable file in Ubuntu using pyinstaller.
If you run py file using pyinstaller -F, it will be created successfully.
Then, when I run the executable file, I get the following error.
Is there a workaround?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SM_0422a_recog_ok.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/home/jmp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/home/jmp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "/home/jmp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 124, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.framework.load_library'
[11772] Failed to execute script SM_0422a_recog_ok
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like some tensorflow modules are missing

```
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.framework.load_library'
```

try to install a different version of tensorflow with pip

Comment: We changed the tensorflow-gpu to 1.6.0 using pip.

Then another error occurs.

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /tmp/_MEI1Zj6td/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so: Can not open shared object file: No such file or directory